# Ionic how to read json array

Tags: json, ionic-framework

How can i read json array.it load like this
[image]

i load json arr using this code -

```
example.controller('ExhibitionTabCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get("json/pills.json")
      .success(function (response) 
      {
       console.log(response);
       $scope.users = response;
      });
    }]);
```

In list view red my json data like this

```
<ion-view title="Sig">
 <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ExhibitionTabCtrl"> 

<ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
       <ion-list>
           <ion-item ng-repeat="x in users|orderBy:'name'">
           {{ x.name + ', ' + x.full_name+', '+x.description}}
           </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>  



</ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

But data not showing in list view.how can i solve this.can any one help me here.Thanks.

Comment: It seems perhaps you might need `$scope.users = response.Sheet1`?

Comment: Great. I have submitted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kosala, you need to specify `$scope.users = response.Sheet1` rather than `$scope.users = response`.